# JavaFX in Eclipse - Error warnings in FXML?

Tags: javafx, editor, warnings, fxml

I'm new to FXML and JavaFX in general.
I'm using eclipse and I wonder if there's any warnings or showing errors in the FXML editor possible to use just like in the normal Java Editor. If there is, how do I activate it?

I've searched around but can't seem to find it. Thanks!